# How to enable in WebStorm the window that show the beginning of a tag?

Tags: html, typescript, webstorm

In Android Studio i have this help when i click at the end of a method or function:

[image: 1]]

How i can enable the same in WebStorm?
This happen to me on the .ts file that have HTML TAGS.

Comment: Works for me in PhpStorm for PHP and JavaScript functions as well as HTML tags (in Blade template) -- https://postimg.cc/8fF2cKG8, If you hover over closing folding mark (red rectangle) it will show even bigger preview) https://postimg.cc/9zr5LM7x. Obviously, matching top folding element must be hidden at that moment.

Comment: @LazyOne When i hover on the closed tags or closed brackets i don't see any window (even when the top tag or bracket is hide).

Comment: Show how it looks in your IDE then (screenshots, or better a video). You may have disabled something etc. P.S. Show whole IDE window to get more details (you can blur private stuff. .. or just use some test project).

Comment: i edited the question. This happen to me only in html tags in a ts file.

Comment: Please report it to JetBrains/WebStorm team: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WEB. So far I was able to locate this ticket only, which is about TypeScript and not HTML: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-36959

Comment: How i can do that? From jetbrains website or directly from WebStorm?

Comment: Yes, you can use appropriate option in a Help menu of WebStorm .. or create a ticket at WebStorm Issue Tracker directly: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WEB and they will sort it out (they may ask for code sample or whatever else they may need to properly understand the issue and will tell if it's a bug, missing functionality or some sort of misconfiguration).